# PowerShell : use parameter validation without throwing exception

Tags: exception, powershell, command-line-arguments

I'd like to call a PowerShell script this way :
`script.ps1 -path mypath\to\files\ -days 6 -hours 0`

To validate the command line arguments, I can either do it by hand, either rely on the `param` syntax :

```
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true )] [string] $path,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [int]    $days,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [int]    $hours
)
```

If I use the `param` syntax :

- the param definition must be the first line in the script (excluding comments). Okay, not a problem for me
- in case of incorrect parameters, I can't catch the error (for example to display  a custom error message)

I'd like to display a custom error message when the script is called with wrong parameters.
**Is it possible, and how, to catch the exception in case of parameter error ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So okay, it is not possible to use `param` AND to catch the related exceptions.

Comment: It still seems to be possible, see my answer.

Comment: My vote was +1 because I understood the question in a different way and in this way it was interesting. Perhaps I should have abstained, the question is not clear. You may try to edit it and explain the problem better. I'll try to help again.

Answer (score 1):

The examples are for functions (simple and advanced) but the same idea should work for scripts with `param` as well:

```
# Simple function.
# Everything not declared in `param` goes to $args.
# If $args is not empty then there are "invalid" parameters or "unexpected" arguments
function test {
    param (
        [string]$path,
        [int]$days,
        [int]$hours
    )
    # check $args and throw an error (in here we just write a warning)
    if ($args) { Write-Warning "Unknown arguments: $args" }
}
```

Or

```
# Advanced function.
# For an advanced function we can use an extra argument $args
# with an attribute `[Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]`
function test {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true )] [string] $path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [int]    $days,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [int]    $hours,
        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)] $args
    )
    # check $args and throw an error (in this test we just write a warning)
    if ($args) { Write-Warning "Unknown arguments: $args" }
}
```

The following test:

```
# invalid parameter
test -path p -invalid -days 5

# too many arguments
test -path p 5 5 extra
```

in both cases produces the same output:

```
WARNING: Unknown arguments: -invalid
WARNING: Unknown arguments: extra
```

Comment: This don't address the question : how to catch the exception in case of parameter error ? If you have an error on the mandatory paramaters, the script just crash and you can do nothing against it.

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround is to wrap your actual function in another one. Something similar to a private/public relation. Example:

```
function Example-Private
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Arg1,
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Arg2   
   )

   # Do what you need
}

function Example-Public
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [string]$Arg1,
        [string]$Arg2   
    )

    try
    {
       Example-Private $Arg1 $Arg2
    }
    catch
    {
       # Display a user-friendly message, save exception into a log file, etc.
    }
}
```

If you are working on a module you could take a look here how to export your public functions and hide the private ones: [Export Powershell Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032344/how-to-hide-helper-functions-in-powershell-modules)

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Powershell v5

Answer (score -1):

In the `Begin` block you can always do further validation on the parameters but if the parameter is wrong, I think you wouldn't want to continue execution.  That is, you'd want to throw a terminating error.  Here's an example:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true )] [string] $path,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [int]    $days,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [int]    $hours
)

Begin {
    if ($hours -lt 0 -or $hours -gt 23) {
        throw "Hours parameter must be between 0 and 23"
    }
}
```

That said, I'm not sure that's any better than using PowerShell's built-in parameter validation functionality e.g.:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true )] [string] $path,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [int]    $days,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [ValidateRange(0,23)]
    [int]
    $hours
)
```

Comment: This don't work. It don't allow the code to catch any exception during the 'param' validation, for exemple if I add an extra parameter.

Comment: Which `this` doesn't work?  The first example, which is doing manual validation or the second example which uses parameter validation.  I suspect you mean the latter didn't work.  Did you try the approach in the first example - validating in the Begin block?

Comment: I tested the first example. I run with script.ps1 -path xxx -dummy yyy and an exception is fired without executing 'begin'.

Comment: `-Dummy` is not a declared parameter.  If you want to handled invalid parameters then don't use `[Parameter(...)]`.

Comment: This is the question. If you know this is not possible, why give a wrong answer ?

Answer (score -1):

you can do that with the param syntax, if you add a string-type dummy-parameter with the property "ValueFromRemainingArguments".
Then you can check this dummy-parameter in your script and take appropriate actions, e.g.:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [SWITCH]$myparam1,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [SWITCH]$myparam2,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
    [STRING]$dummy     
    )

if ($dummy -eq anythingYouDontLike) throwAMessageOrSomething.
```

Comment: As far as I understand this doesn't address the question, which is how to avoid the script crashing if one of the param validation fails, which happens before even reaching your "ValueFromRemainingArguments"