# Gracefully handle Parameter Set violations

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I am transitioning from an "old" group of parameters to a "new" group, and in the transition I want to provide meaningful logging. I have started looking at Parameter Sets, but I am not seeing a way to handle violations gracefully when the parameters are passed from a shortcut to a script. I don't want to have PS fail, I want to trap the condition, but so far as I can tell you can't wrap the Param() section in a try/catch and handle it separately. Is there some way to handle this that I am missing?

Comment: The simplest thing to do would be to introduce a new cmdlet entirely, with either a new name, or the same name but in a new module/script file, and rewriting the old version to 1) always log and 2) transform and forward to the new version. Writing one cmdlet to handle all forms would be madness, even if it could work, if only because it would be really confusing to consumers ("yes I know this is how it's documented, but you can also pass this completely different set because MAGIC").

Comment: I may have made it sound more complicated than it is. In the old version, I had -applySet and -conformSet, which are mutually exclusive, which I validate and provide logging for error conditions. Then each also had to be validated against the data. My new approach is to just use a -setList argument, then test against the data to see if it correctly defines an Apply Set, a Conform Set, or an error condition to log. I want to support users who still use the old approach, with a warning, with a single script, because the tool needs to continue to work with no changes during the transition.

Comment: Seems like you should get what you want by making `ApplySet`, `ConformSet` and `SetList` all required parameters of their own parameter sets (using `ParameterSetName`). Then, in the script, just check if `$ApplySet` is supplied (if so, warn but assign `$SetList` from it and continue), if `$ConformSet` is supplied (ditto) or just proceed with `$SetList`. Even if things get more complicated than this, what always works is to drop parameter sets (or make them very liberal) and check required values in the script. The user experience is less but the checks are still good.

Comment: Jeroen, that's basically it, but I also want to catch and log errors like having ApplySet and SetList defined. But as far as I can tell, in that condition I am going to be dumped out to the PS error handling, which is pretty scary for non technical users. I would rather catch that condition and offer a nice log item like "Can use applySet with SetList" and then exit the script. But you make it sound like there is a way to suppress PS errors associated with Parameter Sets.

Comment: if you want try catch maybe use `validateScript`?

Comment: Hmm, this looks promising.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481662/powershell-use-parameter-validation-without-throwing-exception
Basically accept all input, then use try/catch with functions that do the validation. Testing now.

Comment: "But I also want to catch and log errors like having ApplySet and SetList defined". OK, but that call will never be issued by old clients who don't know about SetList, and new clients who try doing this will be prevented by PowerShell, and they will be able to see that this combination is not allowed/meaningful by consulting the help. Seems to me like you're being overly friendly to the users. ...but then, I realize how bad that sounds. :-)

Comment: The key is, Users in this case is not anyone familiar with powerShell. If they EVER see powershell errors I have failed. Architects need coddling. ;)

Comment: In that case, what you really want is simple: not parameter sets. Simply allow any and all parameters and then check yourself what is and is not supplied and issue appropriate warnings. The whole point of parameter sets is so that PowerShell can do the checking for you, but that's not what you want. For purposes of sanity I recommend putting the "core" functionality in functions that *do* use the appropriate sets, then wrap this in a coddle-proof outer script that does all checking manually before invoking the meat.

Comment: Indeed, that is starting to look like the solution. But so often I "roll my own" only to find there was a build in PS approach that handles it better for less effort. So, I try to exhaust that option before I resort to making any new wheels. ;)